# Unable to hide FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I am working on an Android Instant Chat Application.In the Chat Activity ,i am using a FrameLayout .Following is the xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FCAB26"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view_messages"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".60"
    android:background="@null"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"></ListView>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight=".10"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgSmile"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_msg_panel_smiles"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10sp"/>

    <com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText
        android:id="@+id/edtMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:hint="Enter Message"
        android:layout_weight=".60"></com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSendMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Send Message" />
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/emojicons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".30"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

I have set the visibility of the frame as gone but still it is occupying the area .I want FrameLayout not to occupy space in the beginning .ImageView,EditText and Send Message button should be at the bottom of the screen.On clicking the ImageView ,emoji panel is shown and soft keyboard is hidden,i have used the following code for it:

```
 imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            hideKeyboard();  // hiding the keyboard
            showEmojiPopUp(!showEmoji);
        }
    });

// Displaying the FrameLayout containing the list of Emoticons
public void showEmojiPopUp(boolean showEmoji) {
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.emojicons);
    frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

// Hiding the FrameLayout containing the list of Emoticons
public void hideEmojiPopUp(boolean hideEmoji) {
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.emojicons);
    frameLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

It is working fine.So my problem is how can i set my frame invisible while the activity is created .It should be displayed on clickinh image view.The height of Soft Keyboard and FameLayout should be same.Screenshots are given below :

**1.Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

**2. On clicking image view**

[image]

**3. On clicking EditText**
[image]

Please help me fix the issue .

Comment: I think in this case you should not use weight in this case. Try giving it fix height

Comment: what about `setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are using weights.
remove weightsum and layouts_weight  and use wrap_content.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/emojicons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

and give framelayout its height dynamically.

```
int  deviceHeight;
FrameLayout frameLayout;

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);

            deviceHeight = size.y;

frameLayout= (FrameLayout ) findViewById(R.id.emojicons);

        frameLayout.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (deviceHeight / 3);
    frameLayout.requestLayout();
```

and instead of

```
public void hideEmojiPopUp(boolean hideEmoji) {
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.emojicons);
    frameLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

use this

```
public void hideEmojiPopUp(boolean hideEmoji) {
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.emojicons);
    frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aakash.It is working for me .Can u please tell me how to control the height of soft keyboard?Actually in my case height of soft keyboard and emoji keyboard is different.I want to make it equal .

Answer (score 1):

use `View.GONE` instead of `View.INVISIBLE`

```
// Hiding the FrameLayout containing the list of Emoticons
public void hideEmojiPopUp(boolean hideEmoji) {
   FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.emojicons);
   frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

**View.INVISIBLE**

> This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout
>   purposes.

**View.GONE**

> This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout
>   purposes.

Comment: On clicking image view ,everything is working fine.But problem is when first time chat activity is created ,FrameLayout is occupying some space .U can see in the xml file that i have set the visibility as gone for it .I dont want FrameLayout to occupy some space here .

Answer (score 0):

You are using INVISIBLE instead of GONE. INVISIBLE only hide the view but not leave the space, In case of gone it remove empty space too. So use GONE here.

Comment: I am getting problem in designing the screen of Chat Activity .As u can see ,i want a listview ,a linear layout (containing imageview,edittext,Send message button ) and a frame layout in the design.I have used linear layout to solve my purpose.But it is not working for me.I had used weight earlier .So even after setting the visibilty as gone ,frame layout was occupying some space .When i removed the weight from linear layout and assign fixed height ,still its not working for me .

Comment: You need to take First A LinearLayout as a main Parent with "Match_Parent" width and height and orientation vertical. Inside this LinearLayout take a ListView with width match_parent and hight 0dp. and give weight 1. now take another LinearLayout indise this design layout for image, edittext nad send button.close this LinearLayout here and finally create your view for imozy.